# nginx could not resolve url and 404 returns

Tags: nginx, openshift, kestrel

using nginx inside openshift to route my requests to webapi openshift services. These requests come from a js client, axios POST calls (`https://service.myapp.com/service1`). So far was so good. I need to add a token refresh call to my tokenservice. So, inside js client, I made a check, if necesary, send a post to tokenservice  `https://token.myapp.com/refresh` route. This request is routed to **tokenservice** from nginx successfully.  When received the new token, send another POST to my original service URL `https://service.myapp.com/service1`. However this time nginx could not route the request to service api and 404 rececived. This 404 response has a response header `server: Kestrel`. On the other hand, my initial successful call to **service1** (200 response) had `server: nginx:1.17.8`. Why has the nginx started not to route my /service1 call after token refresh call?  What am I missing?

nginx configuration is as follows.

```
 server {
                  listen 8081 ssl http2;
                  ssl_certificate  /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem;
                  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/cert.key;
                  server_name service.myapp.com;
                  
                  location ~ /servicex1 {
                              proxy_pass  https://servicex1:49253;
                              proxy_http_version 1.1;
                              proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                              proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                              proxy_set_header   Connection $connection_upgrade;
                              proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                              proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                              proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                              proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                              proxy_connect_timeout       600;
                              proxy_send_timeout          600;
                              proxy_read_timeout          600;
                              send_timeout                600;
                            }
                  location ~ /servicex2 {
                              proxy_pass  https://servicex2:49253;
                              proxy_http_version 1.1;
                              proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                              proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                              proxy_set_header   Connection $connection_upgrade;
                              proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                              proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                              proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                              proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;                           
                              proxy_connect_timeout       600;
                              proxy_send_timeout          600;
                              proxy_read_timeout          600;
                              send_timeout                600;                           
                            }                                  
                 
                  location / {
                              proxy_pass  https://myservers;
                              proxy_http_version 1.1;
                              proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                              proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                              proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                              proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;       
                              proxy_connect_timeout       600;
                              proxy_send_timeout          600;
                              proxy_read_timeout          600;
                              send_timeout                600;                           
                            }                 
                }



 server {
                  listen 8081 ssl http2;
                  ssl_certificate  /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem;
                  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/cert.key;
                  server_name token.myapp.com;                   
                  
                  location / {
                              proxy_pass  https://tokenmicroservice:26560;
                              proxy_http_version 1.1;
                              proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                              proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                              proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                              proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;       
                              proxy_connect_timeout       600;
                              proxy_send_timeout          600;
                              proxy_read_timeout          600;
                              send_timeout                600;                           
                            }

                  location ~ /refresh {
                              proxy_pass  https://tokenmicroservice:26560;
                              proxy_http_version 1.1;
                              proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                              proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                              proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                              proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;       
                              proxy_connect_timeout       600;
                              proxy_send_timeout          600;
                              proxy_read_timeout          600;
                              send_timeout                600;                          
                            }  
                  location ~ /login {
                              proxy_pass  https://tokenmicroservice:26560;
                              proxy_http_version 1.1;
                              proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                              proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                              proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                              proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;       
                              proxy_connect_timeout       600;
                              proxy_send_timeout          600;
                              proxy_read_timeout          600;
                              send_timeout                600;                          
                            }                               
                }
```

Comment: When the response contains `server: Kestrel` it seems that you are not querying your NGINX Pod but a Kestrel web server implementation (ASP.NET Core). It is very hard for us to know where you might have such a web server in your environment? Have you set the correct proxies or DNS servers?

Comment: You're right @Simon. The problem was my route definitions in openshift. I made all the routes go to nginx service. Now it's OK.  Thanks